# Jquery Inner div click not working while using color box plug in

Tags: jquery

I'm using colorbox on a div. I have nested div's. When i click the inner div,it is popping up the image in the light box but instead on click the inner div it has to take to next page.

Is there any way to do this?

```
$(".x").colorbox({html:"<img src='test.jpg' />"});

<div class="x">
<div class="y" >
<a href="test.html" >link</a>
</div>
</div>
```

When i click on the link i have to redirect user to test.html. How do i prevent the popup?

Any help would be appreciated!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do `e.stopPropagation()` first on click of the innerdiv. Check the demo in http://jsfiddle.net/nmdsS/ .